# How to use "HTML form target self"?

Tags: php, html, forms, target

I have a database with some numbers assigned to a fake account (PHP).
I try to contact the database (with success) and get the right result from the form.

My issue is that the form result open a new page and display there...
I would really like the result to be displayed IN the module I use to send the form OR anywhere else on the same page I used to send the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form 
    method="post"
    action="http://ggdbase.dx.am/impulseGetInfo.php" 
    target="_self">

     Account name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="name" value="derps">
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Click To Load Account Info">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

[This is what the module look like (on Enjin.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pxKl.jpg)

[image]

[This is what I get when clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJpM0.jpg)

[image]

I did try replacing '_self' with '_blank' or parent and all the other options I could find but none of them gave me a different result :S

Could it be caused by the Enjin system itself ?

Comment: target is support on anchor tags <a>. It wont support for <form> tags hence you wont get the result. may be you can look for another options with javascript and ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `target`. And replace the `action` as

```
action=""
```

This will ensure that you are calling the same page. Write the PHP code there itself.

Hope that help!